# link of a vertex in the triangulation of $S^k$ is a triangulation of $S^{k-1}$?

Tags: combinatorics, general-topology, algebraic-topology, simplicial-complex

Let $C$ be a triangulation of sphere $S^k$, i.e., $C$ is a geometric simplicial complex and the union of all simplices in $C$ is homeomorphic to $S^k$.

For a vertex $v$ of $C$, $$link_C(v):=\{\sigma\in C: \sigma\cap \{v\}=\emptyset, \sigma\cup\{v\}\in C\}.$$

One claims that $link_C(v)$ is a triangulation of $S^{k-1}$.

I try some examples in the small $k$ cases and feel it is true. But I don't know how to prove the claim. Perhaps there is some topological way to view this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The link is a *homology* sphere, ie has the homology of a sphere. To see this, denote the link at $v$ by $L$ and the star at $v$ by $S$. Note that $L$ is homotopy equivalent to $S - v$ and both $S$ and $C - v$ are contractible. So
$$\tilde H_*(L) \cong \tilde H_*(S - v) \cong H_{* + 1}(S, S - v) \cong H_{* + 1}(C, C - v) \cong \tilde H_{* + 1}(C)$$
where the third isomorphism is by excision.
So $L$ is a $(k - 1)$-homology sphere.

To see that the link need not always be a sphere, let $X$ be a homology sphere that is not a sphere (for instance the [Poincaré homology sphere](http://www.map.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/Poincar%C3%A9%27s_homology_sphere)). Then its double suspension $\Sigma^2X$ *is* a sphere, by the [double suspension theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_suspension_theorem). Now, consider two cases.

1. $\Sigma X$ is also a sphere. Then, take $C = \Sigma X$, and $v$ to be either suspension point in $\Sigma X$. Then $\text{link}(v) = X$, which by assumption is not a sphere.
2. $\Sigma X$ is not a sphere. Then, take $C = \Sigma^2 X$, and $v$ to again be either suspension point (now in $\Sigma^2 X$). Then $\text{link}(v) = \Sigma X$, which by assumption is not a sphere.

In either case, we have $C$ is a sphere but $\text{link}(v)$ is not.

Comment: I am wondering can you give an example or reference in which the link is not a sphere? A proof will be even more appreciated.

Comment: Are you asking for a reference to [double suspension of a homology sphere is a sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_suspension_theorem)? Or are you asking how this provides a counterexample?

Comment: I am asking why the link is a homology sphere? And in which case that homology sphere is not a sphere? (For example, a triangle is a triangulation of $S^1$ and the link is indeed $S^0$)

Comment: Now I understand the link is a homology sphere. While why the link is not a sphere? Any counterexample? (Can the Poincare homology sphere be the link of triangulation of some higher dimension sphere?)

Comment: @Connor added some more details and matched the notation with the question.