# When does a topological space have a triangulation?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I am wondering when does a topological space have a triangulation?
As an [example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4454129/link-of-a-vertex-in-the-triangulation-of-sk-is-a-triangulation-of-sk-1) I hear recently, does Poincare homology sphere have a triangulation?

Comment: Yes for the Poincaré homology sphere. See for example Anders Björner and Frank H. Lutz, "Simplicial manifolds, bistellar flips and a 16-vertex triangulation of the Poincaré homology 3-sphere", Experiment. Math. 9 (2000), no. 2, 275-289. (This triangulation is used in SageMath: https://github.com/sagemath/sage/blob/develop/src/sage/topology/simplicial_complex_examples.py#L602.)

Comment: Beyond that, what are you looking for? There are results like: every smooth manifold is triangulable, or every regular CW complex is triangulable — that is, classes of spaces which are triangulable.

Comment: This might have a lot of information you are looking for: https://web.stanford.edu/~cm5/tm.pdf

Comment: Your question is extremely broad, perhaps too broad to be answerable. For instance, its only since 2013 that we have known, from work of Manolescu, that there exist topological manifolds in every dimension $\ge 5$ that are not triangulable. In the other direction the comment of @JohnPalmieri says that smoothable manifolds are triangulable, and the link in that comment of Alvin includes a complete answer to the quesiton in the case of topological manifolds.

Comment: Also: although it's been known for a while that smooth manifolds are triangulable, it is quite recent (2010) that explicit triangulations for $\mathbb{C}P^n$ were known for $n \geq 3$. I expect there are plenty of spaces which are known to be triangulable but for which there is no known explicit triangulation.

Comment: What definition of the Poincare homology sphere you know and what did you try to construct a triangulation of it? With the most common definition, the existence of a triangulation is almost immediate.