# Does a sphere always admit a triangulation in which the link of a vertex is a sphere?

Tags: combinatorics, general-topology, simplicial-complex, triangulation

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4454129/29780), it is asked whether for any triangulation $C$ of a sphere $S^k$, and for any vertex $v$ of $C$, the [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplicial_link) of $v$ is homeomorphic to a sphere $S^{k-1}$.
[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4454221/29780) shows a concrete example of a triangulation of $S^5$ that does not have this property.

MY QUESTION: given a length parameter $\delta$, does there always exist *some* triangulation of $S^k$ with simplices of diameter at most $\delta$, that has the above property?

My guess is that the barycentric triangulation should satisfy this property, but I do not know how to prove it (if it is true).

Comment: Is the property preserved when you go from a triangulation tomits barycentric subdivision?